# Doubling every letter in a statement

Tags: java, for-loop, stringbuilder

For my intro to java class I have an assignment that asks us to use the scanner class and a for loop and and if statement to double every letter in a statement, while tripling every exclamation point in that statement. I don't know how to do both in a for loop. This is what I have so far:

```
public class DoubleLetters {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String newString = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            newString += str.charAt(j) + str.charAt(j);
        }
        return newString;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct for the double every letter part. However, you have to add a condition for the exclamation point part.

```
public class DoubleLetters{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        String newString = "";
        String str = "input string!"

        for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){

            if(str.charAt(j) == '!')
            {
                newString += str.charAt(j) + str.charAt(j) + str.charAt(j);
            }
            else
            {
                newString += str.charAt(j) + str.charAt(j);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(newString);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: do i have the declare the variable j?

Comment: nope, you already declared it in this part `for (int j = 0; ...`

Comment: hm, i keep coming up with an error for that line saying "compilation error (line 4, column 29) : cannot find symbol"

Comment: oh wait, you haven't declared any string yet, `str` is not defined. I'll update my answer

Comment: one more question, it says i cant return with a void, how do i print to the console instead?

Comment: updated the answer, hope you study JAVA more and not just rely on help of the stackoverflow community. Do some practice to understand different syntax for the programming language you are dealing with.